# Obteniendo coordenadas con js y php

Tags: javascript, php

Tengo un pequeño proyecto para obtener la latitud y longitud según la ubicación del dispositivo, las obtengo con javascript y las mando a php. Me funciona a la perfección pero de momento solo puedo obtenerlas al dar clic en un botón en el evento click. Lo que no he podido hacer es que no se necesite el botón sino que las coordenadas se obtengan en cuanto carga la página.
Aquí el código de mi archivo con el script de javascript:

```
const funcionInit = () => {
    if (!"geolocation" in navigator) {
        return alert("Tu navegador no soporta el acceso a la ubicación. Intenta con otro");
    }

    const RUTA_API = "./loguear.php";

    let idWatcher = null;

    const $latitud = document.querySelector("#latitud"),
        $longitud = document.querySelector("#longitud"),
        $btnIniciar = document.querySelector("#btnIniciar"),
        $btnDetener = document.querySelector("#btnDetener"),
        $log = document.querySelector("#log");


    const onUbicacionConcedida = ubicacion => {
        const coordenadas = ubicacion.coords;
        $latitud.innerText = coordenadas.latitude;
        $longitud.innerText = coordenadas.longitude;
        loguear(`${ubicacion.timestamp}: ${coordenadas.latitude},${coordenadas.longitude}`);
        enviarAServidor(ubicacion);
    }

    const enviarAServidor = ubicacion => {

        const otraUbicacion = {
            coordenadas: {
                latitud: ubicacion.coords.latitude,
                longitud: ubicacion.coords.longitude,
            },
            timestamp: ubicacion.timestamp,
        };
        console.log("Enviando: ", otraUbicacion);
        fetch(RUTA_API, {
            method: "POST",
            body: JSON.stringify(otraUbicacion),
        }); 
    };

    const loguear = texto => {
        $log.innerText += "\n" + texto;
    };

    const onErrorDeUbicacion = err => {

        $latitud.innerText = "Error obteniendo ubicación: " + err.message;
        $longitud.innerText = "Error obteniendo ubicación: " + err.message;
        console.log("Error obteniendo ubicación: ", err);
    }

    const detenerWatcher = () => {
        if (idWatcher) {
            navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(idWatcher);
        }
    }

    const opcionesDeSolicitud = {
        enableHighAccuracy: true, 
        maximumAge: 0, 
        timeout: 5000 
    };


    $btnIniciar.addEventListener("click", () => {
        detenerWatcher();
        idWatcher = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(onUbicacionConcedida, onErrorDeUbicacion, opcionesDeSolicitud);
    });

    $btnDetener.addEventListener("click", detenerWatcher);

    $latitud.innerText = "Cargando...";
    $longitud.innerText = "Cargando...";


};
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", funcionInit);
```

Aquí mi archivo php donde mando los valores de la ubicación a variables:

```
$ubicacion = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
$mensaje = "Timestamp: " . $ubicacion->timestamp . PHP_EOL;
$mensaje .= "Latitud: " . $ubicacion->coordenadas->latitud . PHP_EOL;
$mensaje .= "Longitud: " . $ubicacion->coordenadas->longitud . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
file_put_contents("ubicaciones.txt", $mensaje, FILE_APPEND);
```

Y aquí mi html donde están los botones a los que hago referencia en el script de js:

```
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description">
    <meta name="author">
    <title>Prueba ubicación</title>
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T"
     crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <main role="main" class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                <h1>Prueba</h1>
                <br>
                <button id="btnIniciar" class="btn btn-info">Iniciar</button>
                <button id="btnDetener" class="btn btn-danger">Detener</button>
                <br>
                <strong>Latitud: </strong> <span id="latitud"></span>
                <strong>Longitud: </strong> <span id="longitud"></span>
                <br>
                <a href="./ubicaciones.txt">Ver ubicaciones</a>
                <br>
                <pre id="log"></pre>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
    <script src="script.js">
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Como mencioné si está funcional al momento de obtener los datos de ubicación, los pasa a una variable php y los guarda en un archivo .txt, el problema es que necesito del evento de un botón para obtener la latitud y longitud y lo que no sé hacer es que acceda a la ubicación del dispositivo sin necesidad de dicho botón. Agradezco su apoyo y quedo atento a sus comentarios. gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba esto:

***Con JS:***

```
window.onload=function (){
  //Código a ejecutar una vez se carga la pagina
  console.log("READY")
}
```

***Con JQuery:***

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  //Codigo que quieras ejecutar  
});
```

***CDN requerido con JQuery:***

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.js" integrity="sha256-3zlB5s2uwoUzrXK3BT7AX3FyvojsraNFxCc2vC/7pNI=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Funciona, muchas gracias. Una consulta adicional, ahora vacío los datos en un txt ¿Cómo puedo almacenar la latitud y longitud en variables php para mandarlas a una bd?

Comment: Los datos cargados en variables js a variables php?

Comment: Osea mandar las coordenadas que ya obtuve en js a variables en php, si te fijas puedo obtener esos valores en el archivo php pero las mando a un txt, como hacer para que se guarde el valor en una variable php que pueda utilizar para mandar a un bd

Comment: Deberías de hacer otra pregunta referente a esa nueva duda ya que así funciona el sitio.

Comment: Debido a que `Js` trabajo del lado del cliente y `php` del lado del servidor no se pueden pasar datos así sin más por lo tanto hice algo, pase la latitud y la longitud al `LocalStorage` por medio de `JS` luego para trabajar del lado del servidor utilice `AJAX` y recupere esa data y después la pase a **2 variables PHP**.